# Get all messages which I sent with @username (Conversation of me & user)

Tags: support, chat, display-names

I want all messages from a chat room which I ping to a particular user (conversation of me & user).

There are many users that changed their profile name and pic, so we can't identify those users. I just want all messages which I sent with `@username` to that user in a chat room. Is it possible to get all those messages?

Example: I chatted with [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226882/droid-dev) some months ago, then he changed his name & profile pic. How can I find messages which I sent to this user?

Comment: Have you tried the chat search feature?

Comment: What I type in **search for** field, I forgot that user's old name and also forgot that chat room.

Comment: If you don't know what to search for or even where, you'll probably have to go though all your chat messages.

Comment: @Lix I just want conversation of mine and particular users, is it possible ?

Comment: is SO database deleting some old messages?

Comment: That search will look for messages **by** `droid_dev` - messages where he mentions you. I think you meant to do the [other way around](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=droid_dev&user=624069&room=).

Comment: @Lix no, he changed his name so I can't got old messages..by the way thanks. first query is fine.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, the `@name` is integral part of the chat message itself and there's no record as far as I know of the "pinged" user.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a search query with some useful parameters:

```
https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=QUERY&user=YOUR_USER_ID&room=ROOM_ID
```

As you can see, it is possible to specify which user's messages you want to search (who sent the message) and also in what room.

Other than navigating directly to that URL, you can fill in a search form when in the chat area on the chat sites. For example:

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search (search Stack Overflow chat)
- https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search (search Meta Stack Exchange chat)

Comment: What I type in search for field, I forgot that user's old name and also forgot that chat room.

Comment: add this [query](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%40CapDroid&User=1226882&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=relevance) in your answer.